# I want to change positive negative and neutral sentiments into an array

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to convert negative and neutral positive to array

`Label = np.where.(df['Sentimen']=='Negative', 'Netral','Positive', 0,1)`

---

`y = labely[45:75]`

I use algorithm naive bayes and particle swarm optimization n k fold

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

i believe you want to convert positive negative and neutral to numbers, you can use this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
number = LabelEncoder()
df['sentiment] = number.fit_transform(df['sentimen'].astype('str'))
df
```

Comment: I want to use array for optimazion y_train